# What does "template <> int line<0>::operator[](int y) const" do?

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, template-specialization

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

constexpr int mod = 1e9 + 7, maxn = 2e6;
int N, M, p[1 << 10], buf[maxn];

template <bool t> struct line {
    int *v;
    int operator[](int y) const;
};       

template <> int line<0>::operator[](int y) const { return v[y]; }
template <> int line<1>::operator[](int y) const { return v[M * y]; }
```

What is this operator thing? Is it a function? If it is then why does it have square brackets and "const" after it?
Also do these template things mean? I'm assuming that it executes one of them
depending on the value of t ( true or false )'

Comment: Wherever you learned `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`, avoid that.  Unless you intend to learn C++ wrong, in which case you're off to a good start.  Otherwise, I recommend a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/4641116).

Comment: I recommend you get out of the habit of using [`using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/10077) and [`#include <bits/stdc++.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/10077). They're bad individually, but especially insidious together.

Comment: Check out the tags I've added, and try googling the terms: [tag:templates], [tag:template-specialization], [tag:operator-overloading]. That should get you started while you wait for folks to write answers.

Comment: The two subjects here are "class templates" and "operator overloading". Read up on those 2 chapters, and perhaps this will make more sense.

Comment: Thank you, everyone. This code is not written by me, I found this solution that was from a C++ contest. I was just struggling to understand its meaning

Comment: Code written for contests is never good code.  It's not meant to be readable, it's not meant to be maintainable.  It's meant to solve one problem fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is this operator thing? Is it a function? If it is then why does it have square brackets

You're declaring `operator[]` as a member function of the class template named `line`. By providing this, we say that we're **overloading** `operator[]` for our class template `line`(really for a specific class type that will be instantiated).

---

> why does it have `const` after it

The `const` means that this `operator[]` member function is a **const member function**. Meaning we're not allowed to change the non-static non-mutable data members inside this member function.

---

> Also do these template things mean?

Assuming you are asking about the `template<>` as the question title suggests, it means that you're **explicitly(fully)specializing** the member function `operator[]` for different class-template arguments `0` and `1`.

---

More details can be found in any of the [good C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Also refer to [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h).